# Plus/Minus button not working in IE

Tags: php, html

I got a webshop with a quantity button where you can add or remove products and the amount is shown in the middle.

All works, except in IE (11)

This is the code (positioned in a table):

```
<a href="?del='.$key.'" class="minus" ><input type="button" class="minus" value="-" id="min"></a>

<input type="text" class="input-text qty text" title="Qty" value="'.$value.'" name="quantity" min="1" step="1">

<a href="?add='.$key.'" type="button" class="plus"><input  type="button" class="plus" value="+"></a>
```

Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: could be simple caching by the browser

Comment: I found weird that this code doesn't use `<input type = "number">` because the number input allow you to have 2 "plus/minus" buttons. If you change to "number" the type ?

Comment: I might have a solution, since the buttons are in anchor tags IE is not letting it work. So I want to use an if IE tag, but I see they don't work anymore for IE11, know how to work around this?